# Nginx proxy manager is not being able to serve the page from another docker container

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy, docker-container, docker-network

I am trying for nginx proxy manager (running in a docker container) to connect to another docker container that has port 8080 open on it. When I setup the proxy to connect to `192.168.0.29:8080` the ip address of the host, but it doesn't work, the browser just says that the site didn't send any data.

I tried setting up the reverse proxy with other services (that weren't running inside a docker container), and they worked flawlessly. So, I've concluded, the problem is something with the docker containers.

First, I tried replacing the ip address with the address of the container (shown in portainer) which showed to be `172.17.0.2`. But, that didn't work. I can confirm that both containers are in the same network, `bridge`.

I could not find any solutions for this problem either here, at Stack Overflow, or anywhere else. Hope there's enough data to solve this problem. Thanks ahead of time!

**Edit:**
running `arp -na` from within the container gives this output:

```sh
[root@docker-00244f7ab2cc:/app]# arp -na
? (172.17.0.1) at 02:42:d1:fc:fc:6b [ether] on eth0
```

Comment: If the both are in the same network, then you can use <CONTAINER_NAME> in your nginx settings. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it didn't work either

Comment: Could you try using the gateway ip address for the bridge? You can get it by running `docker inspect bridge --format '{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Yes, I tried that too

Comment: Do you know what ip address your service is binding to? It may be `localhost` and only reachable within the container itself. Try having your service listening on the gateway ip address or `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I could access it from outside with the ip address of the host (192.168.0.29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my question after lots of searching and testing and it's quite simple. The solution is to start the nginx proxy manager docker container on **the ***host*** network** instead of the *bridge* network. Then, you can use localhost and then the port to refer to which service you want to redirect to.

Comment: This worked but now my NGINX Proxy manager is no longer accessible over port 81.  The sites that I had configured are now working though.  How can I have both running?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to set both NGINXPM and your containers on the same non-default bridge network (Default bridge cant resolve hostnames which are easier to work with). Setting your containers on the host networks is not recommended since they are no longer isolated from the rest of your network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).